# Why do I get _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) and/or is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use) assertions?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-c++

When I run my with VisualStudio compiled programs in debug-mode, sometimes I get

> Debug assertion failed! Expression: `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)`

or

> Debug assertion failed! Expression: `is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)`

(or both after each other) assertions.

What does it mean? How can I find and fix the origin of such problems?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These assertions show that either the pointer, which should be freed is not (or no longer) valid (`_CrtIsValidHeapPointer`-assertion) or that the heap was corrupted at some point during the run of the program (`is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)`-assertion aka `_Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse)`-assertion in earlier versions).

When acquiring memory from the heap, functions  `malloc`/`free` don't communicate directly with the OS, but with a memory manager, which is usually provided by the corresponding C-runtime. VisualStudio/Windows SDK provide a special heap-memory manager for debug-builds, which performs additional sanity checks during the run time.

`_CrtIsValidHeapPointer` is just a heuristic, but there are enough cases of invalid pointers, for which this function can report a problem.

**1. When does `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer`-assertion fire?**

There are some of the most usual scenarios:

*A. Pointer doesn't point to a memory from the heap to begin with:*

```c
char *mem = "not on the heap!";
free(mem);
```

here the literal isn't stored on the heap and thus can/should not be freed.

*B. The value of the pointer isn't the original address returned by `malloc`/`calloc`:*

```c
unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char*)malloc(100);
mem++;
free(mem); // mem has wrong address!
```

As value of `mem` is no longer 64byte aligned after the increment, the sanity check can easily see that it cannot be a heap-pointer!

A slightly more complex, but not unusual C++-example (mismatch `new[]` and `delete`):

```cpp
struct A {
    int a = 0;
    ~A() {// destructor is not trivial!
         std::cout << a << "\n";
    }
};
A *mem = new A[10];
delete mem;
```

When `new A[n]` is called, actually  `sizeof(size_t)+n*sizeof(A)`bytes memory are allocated via `malloc` (when the destructor of the class `A` is not trivial), the number of elements in array is saved at the beginning of the allocated memory and the returned pointer `mem` points not to the original address returned by `malloc`, but to address+offset (`sizeof(size_t)`). However, `delete` knows nothing about this offset and tries to delete the pointer with wrong address (`delete []` would do the right thing).

*C. double-free:*

```
unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char*)malloc(10);
free(mem);
free(mem);  # the pointer is already freed
```

A very common reason in C++ that [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/5769463)/five isn't adhered to, e.g:

```cpp
struct A {// bad: doesn't adhere to rule of three
    int* ptr;
    A(int i): ptr(new int(i)){}
    ~A() { delete ptr; }
};

{
  A a(0);
  A b = a; // a and b share pointer: a.ptr == b.ptr
} // here destructors of b and a called => problem
//  at first b.ptr gets deleted
//  deleting (already deleted) a.ptr leads now to UB/error.
```

*D. pointer from another runtime/memory manager*

Windows programs have the ability to use multiple runtimes at once: every used dll could potentially have its own runtime/memory manager/heap, because it was linked statically or because they have different versions. Thus, a memory allocated in one dll, could fail when freed in another dll, which uses a different heap (see for example this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63147214/5769463) or this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35310117/5769463)).

**2. When does `is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)`-assertion fire?**

In the above cases A. and B., in addition also `is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)` will fire. After `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer`-assertion, the `free`-function (more precise `free_dbg_nolock`) looks for info in the block-header (a special data structure used by debug-heap, more information about it later on) and checks that the block type is valid. However, because the pointer is completely bogus, the place in the memory, where `nBlockUse` is expected to be, is some random value.

However, there are some scenarios, when `is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)` fires without previous `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer`-assertion.

*A. `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer` doesn't detect invalid pointer*

Here is an example:

```c
unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char*)malloc(100);
mem+=64;
free(mem);
```

Because debug-heap fills the allocated memory with `0xCD`, we can be sure that accessing `nBlockUse` will yield a wrong type, thus leading to the above assertion.

*B. Corruption of the heap*

Most of the time, when `is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)` fires without `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer` it means, that the heap was corrupted due to some out-of-range writes.

So if we "delicate" (and don't overwrite "no man's land"-more on that later):

```c
unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char*)malloc(100);
*(mem-17)=64; // thrashes _block_use.
free(mem);
```

leads only to `is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)`.

---

In all above cases, it is possible to find the underlying issue by following memory allocations, but knowing more about the structure of debug-heap helps a lot.

An overview about debug-heap can be found e.g. [in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2019), alternatively all details of the implementation can be found in the corresponding Windows Kit,(e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp`).

In a nutshell: When a memory is allocated on a debug heap, more memory than needed is allocated, so additional structures such as "no man's land" and additional info, such as `_block_use`, can be stored next to the "real" memory. The actual memory layout is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| header of the block + no man's land |  "real" memory | no man's land |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    32 bytes         +      4bytes   |     ? bytes    |     4 bytes   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Every byte in "no man's land" at the end and at the beginning are set to a special value (`0xFD`), so once it is overwritten we can register out-of-bounds write access (as long as they are at most 4 bytes off).

For example in the case of `new[]`-`delete`-mismatch we can analyze memory before the pointer, to see whether this is no man's land or not (here as code, but normally done in debugger):

```cpp
A *mem = new A[10];
...
// instead of
//delete mem;
// investigate memory:
unsigned char* ch = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(mem);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    std::cout << (int)(*(ch - i)) << " ";
}
```

we get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 253 253 253 253 0 0 52
```

i.e. the first 8 bytes are used for the number of elements (10), than we see "no man's land" (`0xFD=253`) and then other information. It is easy to see, what is going wrong - if the pointer where correct, the first 4 values where `253`.

When Debug-heap frees memory it overwrites it with a special byte value: `0xDD`, i.e. `221`. One also can restrict the reuse of once used and freed memory by setting flag `_CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF`, thus the memory stays marked not only directly after the `free`-call, but during the whole run of the program. So when we try to free the same pointer a second time, debug-heap can see, taht the memory was already freed once and fire the assertion.

Thus, it is also easy to see, that the problem is a double-free, by analyzing the values around pointer:

```c
unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char*)malloc(10);
free(mem);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    printf("%d ", (int)(*(mem - i)));
}
free(mem); //second free
```

prints

```
221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221 221
```

the memory, i.e. the memory was already freed once.

*On the detection of heap-corruption:*

The purpose of no-man's land is to detect out-of-range writes, this however works only for being off for 4 bytes in either direction, e.g.:

```c
unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char*)malloc(100);
*(mem-1)=64; // thrashes no-man's land
free(mem);
```

leads to

```
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: before Normal block (#13266) at 0x0000025C6CC21050.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory before start of heap buffer.
```

A good way to find heap corruption is to use `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF)` or `ASSERT(_CrtCheckMemory());`(see this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30413066/5769463)). However, this is somewhat indirect - a more direct way it to use `gflags` as explained in this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2476077/5769463) (it is not unusual that `gflags` needs about 30 times more memory and is about 10 times slower).

---

Btw, the definition of `_CrtMemBlockHeader` changed over the time and no longer the one shown in [online-help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2019), but:

```c
struct _CrtMemBlockHeader
{
    _CrtMemBlockHeader* _block_header_next;
    _CrtMemBlockHeader* _block_header_prev;
    char const*         _file_name;
    int                 _line_number;
    
    int                 _block_use;
    size_t              _data_size;
    
    long                _request_number;
    unsigned char       _gap[no_mans_land_size];

    // Followed by:
    // unsigned char    _data[_data_size];
    // unsigned char    _another_gap[no_mans_land_size];
};
```